# Get all values from Django QuerySet plus additional fields from a related model

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I was wondering if there is a shortcut to getting all fields from a Django model and only defining additional fields that are retrieved through a join (or multiple joins).

Consider models like the following:

```
class A(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    y = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
```

Now I can use the [values()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values) function like this

```
B.objects.values('y', 'a__text')
```

to get tuples containing the specified values from the `B` model and the actual field from the `A` model. If I only use

```
B.objects.values()
```

I only get tuples containing fields from the `B` model (i.e., `y` and the foreign key id `a`). Let's assume a scenario where `B` and `A` have many fields, and I am interested in all of those belonging to `B` but only in a single field from `A.` Manually specifying all the field names in the `values()` call would be possible, but tedious and error-prone.

So is there a way to specify that I want all local fields, but only a (few) specific joined field(s)?

*Note: I'm currently using Django 1.11, but if a solution only works with a more recent version I am interested in that too.*

Answer (score 0):

You can use `prefetch_related` for this. See [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related):

> You want to use performance optimization techniques like deferred
>   fields:
>
> queryset = Pizza.objects.only('name')
>
> restaurants = Restaurant.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('best_pizza', queryset=queryset))

In your case you can do something like this:

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

queryset = A.objects.only('text')
b_list = B.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('a', queryset=queryset))
```

Comment: Given that B belongsTo A, should this case require select_related instead of prefetch_related? Assuming you do B.objects...

Comment: @fabio.sussetto `prefetch_related` also may be used with single related object. From the doc: `Custom prefetching also works with single related relations like forward ForeignKey or OneToOneField. There are a number of cases where prefetching with a custom QuerySet is useful`.

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification, kind of forgot that you can use prefetch_related as a more flexible select_related. I guess the other difference is that with prefetch_related you'd always see an extra query, while select_related would use a join in one query.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this would work in your case?

```
B.objects.select_related('a').defer('a__field_to_lazy_load');
```

This will load all fields from both models except the ones you specify in defer(), where you can use the usual Django double underscore convention to traverse the relationship.

The fields you specify in defer() won't be loaded from the db but they will be if you try to access them later on (e.g. in a template).